# Windows 10 screenshot tool with controllable font anti-aliasing?

Tags: screenshot, windows-10

Is there any (preferably free) screenshot tool which allows one to control font-aliasing in the windows it captures and which works under Windows 10? I couldn't find any yet.

I remember that there was "Windows Clippings" (not free BTW) which could entirely disable anti-aliasing but this tool is not free and does not work on Win10 any more. Also in my case just switching it to greyscale AA would work as well and in fact be even better.

Now I could just change the relevant system-wide settings or set up a VM for that purpose but before I do that I just thought I ask.

BTW, if you want to know what I need this tool for: Especially for documents that are meant to be printed it's better not to have pixel images with subpixel anti-aliasing (ClearType®). Call me a perfectionist if you want.

Comment: Have you considered connecting to your own computer through a remote desktop connection? Would this kind of thing work for you? If so, I can write up a more comprehensive answer to this question.

Comment: Ah, because there is a setting for that, great idea! I will later have a quick look whether it really works and give you an OK then.